# Accessing an array's string index with URL argument

Tags: php, string, url, get, arguments

I'm trying to get a script to retrieve a page header from an array using a string index, which works fine when calling directly, but for some reason, does not work when called through a URL argument using $_GET. This is what I'm currently trying to get the title with:

```
Kelvin Shadewing - <?php echo $pageitem[$_GET["id"]]["title"]; ?>
```

And the array with the headers is this:

```
$pageitem = array(
  "home" => array("title" => "Home", "content" => "home.php"),
  "contact" => array("title" => "Contact", "content" => "contact.php")
)
```

The stuff involving content works just fine, so ignore that part. I've tried different ways of getting the header to show up right, even concatenating quotation marks around $_GET, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you appending the URL with either `?id=home` or `?id=contact`?

Comment: Yes. It works just fine for including the content file; it just doesn't want to retrieve the header.

Comment: Do the code blocks appear in the same order as in the question ? Can you provide the full source ?